# Create a Mermaid graph with sideways arrow

Tags: r, mermaid

I have a graph I build in grViz looking like so:

```
    grViz("digraph flowchart {
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = false, width = 1]
      1 [label = 'Initial Cohort - ']
      2 [label = 'Left After Reduction - ']
      3 [label = 'Group 1']
      4 [label = 'Group 2']
      5 [label = 'Group 3']
      m1 [label = 'Excluded: \\l -Reason 1 - X \\l -Reason 2 - Y']
      node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label='']
      p1 -> 2;
      {rank=same; p1 -> m1}
    
      edge [dir=none]
      1 -> p1;
      2 -> 3
      2 -> 4
      2 -> 5
    }")
```

[image]

I want to build the same graph in Mermaid but I can't seem to find the way to make a sidways node in a TD graph without having a subgraph that has visible borders

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please include the code you have used  when building the graph in Mermaid?

Comment: @Peter
I was not successful in building it in mermaid so I did not save any code, but the is like a basic TB graph and I can't seem to find the way to have one bar set off to the side

Comment: OK, just to help with my own ignorance, what does TB stand for. I'm familiar with the term 'flow chart' for these sort of graphs. Were you using the DiagrammeR package?

Comment: Yes, In mermaid TD (Sorry, my mistake) stands for Top-Down, The basic flow chart in mermaid will be:
graph TD;
    A-->B;
    B-->C;
    C-->D;

Comment: I've not found a way to add a branch: it does not seem to be possible except as you not using a subgraph. An alternative is to insert text in the connector but I've not been able to wrap text. You may have bumped into the limits of Mermaid.

Comment: It is not currently possible to do this in mermaidJS.